# Graphical representations for functions of the form y = a f(x + b) + c with parameters a, b, and c

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Original Graph: $f(x) = x^2$

Modified Graph: $f(x) = 2x^2 $

Describe the graph and function behavior, explain in terms of function, inputs, outputs, and graph.

---

Is this Correct?

My answer:

The graph of the function $f(x) = 2x^2$ shrinks towards the vertical axis by a factor of $2$. For any given input of the function $f(x) = 2x^2$, the output is 2 times the input so this makes the graph shrink vertically by a factor of $2$.

Comment: "the output is 2 times the input so this makes the graph shrink vertically" ...It's kind of like saying "I'm twice as big as I was when I was five years old, so I'm a lot smaller now.".

Answer (score 1):

As an educator, I hate describing how the parent function changes with terms like "shrink" or "stretch."  In this case, the function is "stretching" in one direction while "shrinking" in another.

Nevertheless, you should double check your last sentence. You wrote, "...the graph shrink vertically..." which contradicts your first sentence "...shrinks toward the vertical axis..." The first sentence is correct, but that makes the shrinking *horizontal* (left-right). So, in the last sentence, change "vertically" to "horizontally" and your answer is correct.